# Where can I put a user-defined shell function?

Tags: command-line, bash, functions

I am planning to create a function that would simplify things for me. The function  would be something like

```
function lazymode()
{
echo "Hello World!";
}
```

so that when I use the command `lazymode` in the **shell** , it will output the `Hello World!`.

What file should I put the user-defined function?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depends on the function. If it's just a super-simple one-liner like that you could create an alias or stick the function in `~/.bashrc` (a file that bash loads when it starts).

If you're creating something a bit more meaty, it might make more sense to create its own executable script in `~/bin/` which won't exist by default (it's just a directory) but should be in your path. Remember for this the file will need to be executable (`chmod +x filename`) and start with a proper `#!/bin/bash` stanza.

The second route has some clear benefits:

- It's easier to see what's available
- A syntax error won't tank your profile
- You don't need to keep re-sourcing your bash config if you change the script
- It's available to any shell as long as the full path is used or `~/bin/` is in the path for that shell too (which it should be in most cases AFAIK).

Comment: I used the later option. My function contains commands that delete files, wget's something, executes the commands javac and java. and when I tried it on the gnome-terminal, it's not working fine. Do you think there is an issue?

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: It's already fixed. Fixed through this answer

Comment: umm... shouldn't user scripts be in the `/usr/local/bin` instead messing with the `$PATH`?

Comment: It seems to me that a small but worth-mentioning advantage of putting functions in `~/.bashrc` (as it is `source`d) is that Bash looks for functions before doing PATH lookup.

Answer (score 9):

The best choice would be `~/.bashrc` file.

You can either write your shell function definitions directly in your `~/.bashrc` file, or, if you have lots of them and don't want to clutter your `~/.bashrc` file, you can put them all in another file of your choosing -- just be sure to source *that* file in your `~/.bashrc` file. For example, if the file with your functions is named `bash_functions`, simply add in your `~/.bashrc` file the lines:

```
if [[ -f /path/to/bash_functions ]]; then
    source /path/to/bash_functions
fi
```

or, equivalently:

```
if [[ -f /path/to/bash_functions ]]; then
    . /path/to/bash_functions
fi
```

where the `.` is just a symbolic representation of `source`.  The `if` test makes sure the file `/path/to/bash_functions` exists before trying to source it.

This technique is very similar to establishing aliases in `~/.bashrc` by creating a file called `~/.bash_aliases` and using similar syntax to that above in `~/.bashrc` to test for its existence and then source it.

Comment: thanks, it worked. by the way, what is its difference with .profile? in some linux, I cannot put functions in bashrc

Comment: `~/.profile` file is executed by the command interpreter for login shells. When you use GUI and you open the terminal, that file is not executed because you will be in a not login shell.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an essential procedure for declaring a permanent function:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` file in a text editor. Doesn't matter which text editor, so long as you know how to use it and so long as you open the `/home/<username>/.bashrc`
2. At the end of the `~/.bashrc` declare your own function, for instance:

   ```
   find_dirs(){
       find "$1" -type d
   }
   ```
3. Save and close the file.

The `~/.bashrc` file is read every time you open interactive shell (that is new terminal tab, login via `ssh`, or open TTY1 or other virtual console). This will not be available in script files, because `~/.bashrc` is not read for non-interactive shells. It is also not available if you run `bash` with `--norc` option.

If you want the function to be available immediately in the currently open tab, use `source ~/.bashrc` command.

---

Functions take arguments just like regular commands. For example, `$1` through `$9` indicate the positional parameters when you call a function. In the example above `find_dirs` takes one positional parameter only, and would be called as `find_dirs /etc`.  You can also use `$@` to refer to all positional parameters. Functions also accept redirection. You can call a function with `find_dirs $1 > /dev/null`;  we also could declare it as follows:

```
find_dirs(){
    find "$1" -type d
}
```

Note from `man bash`: "Functions are executed in the context of the current shell; no new process is created to interpret them". That means that you also should be aware of functions having ability to alter your shell execution environment - change variables and terminal settings.