# Keep gnome-terminal title while run MC

Tags: gnome-terminal, midnight-commander

I've put a little bash script into my `.bashrc` based on this post:

[How to change Terminal Title in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04/774543)

It works great, at morning I start some terminals, one is called `System` other is for `Development`, etc.. I am using `gnome-terminal`. I am also using `tint2`, so all my terminals are on the bottom taskbar.

It is great to flag my terminals to distinguish them. But when I run midnight commander, it overwrites my given titles. Titles will be: `mc[username@machine-name]`

When I close mc, the titles are ok (what I've set before).

Is it possible to force `mc` somehow to not overwrite my original titles?

Comment: Is the original title re-written automatically after you exit from `mc`? Or do you want help to fix it? (I don't know how fix the title, while mc is running.)

Comment: When I run terminal, title is: `username@machine-name`. I run `set-title xxx` so the title now is `xxx`. Run mc, and title is:  `mc[username@machine-name]`. Exit mc, and title is `xxx`. What I want is to keep `xxx` while I do not close terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Midnight Commander, go to F9 -> Options -> Layout -> disable XTerm window title.

(And then Options -> Save setup, unless you have Auto save setup enabled.)