# How to change the terminal title and the prompt path to show only the current working directory’s name?

Tags: command-line, terminator

I use Terminator terminal. As you can see from the screenshot below, everywhere it shows the directory names. Instead of showing whole directory names, I want it to show only the last directory name i.e `ecommerce` in this case. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However your solution works for title and tab title but in the terminal the it still shows whole directory name. Here I would also like to have only the last name. Is it possible by any chance?

Comment: This last solutions did not change anything. I have updated the photo in the question. I would like to change the `blue` marked directory names to show only last directory name. Your above solutions successfully change the title but it would be nice if I can change the blue marked name as well.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. If you put this as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your `~/.bashrc` in your preferred text editor and search the `PS1` line, by default it says

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

To change your prompt, i.e. the coloured part in front of every command line, to show only the current working directory’s name instead of its path, change `\w` to `\W`:

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

To set the terminal’s (or terminal tab’s) title to the cwd you need to append `\[\e]2;\W\a\]` to this line, this can be done e.g. at the end directly before the closing `'` or – because the line is long enough – on a separate line directly afterwards:

```bsh
PS1=$PS1'\[\e]2;\W\a\]' # set terminal title to cwd
```

Use `\w` instead of `\W` for the full cwd path.

#### Related questions

- [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22413/507051)
- [How to change Terminal Title in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/774532/507051)