# How to prevent terminal title changing after ssh

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, ssh, gnome-terminal

I use [one of the many solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04/774543#774543) to set the terminal title:

Function in `.bashrc`:

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

And it works perfectly! But when I ssh to a remote host, the title is changed to `ubuntu@remote.host.name`.

Is there any solution to prevent title changing after ssh?

Comment: You probably need to put this in your remote machine's .bashrc as well.@i.bondarenko

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the remote machine's `.bashrc`. Some of them in production environment so any modification on them is restricted. Others are test servers and their uptime very short so I need to modify `.bashrc` many times per day. But anyway thank you for the suggestion @Pie.

Comment: I tried to combine "ssh + set_title_command" and wrapp it into alias, but without success.

Comment: Combine how? I'd use `alias myssh="ssh servername;set_title"`

Comment: @waltinator Thank you for the suggestion.
I have tried:
`alias myssh="ssh ubuntu@host;set-title my_title1"` but without success.

Comment: Aliases won't work as they will still run on the _client_, not the remote machine. And `set-title` will only be invoked _after_ `ssh` ends, i.e., when you disconnect from the remote.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470061/change-title-for-tabs-in-terminator/1473378#1473378

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot modify `~/.bashrc` I assume you also cannot *create or copy **any*** file to the remote user's `~`, right? Because if you can, then just add a `~/.bash_aliases` that reverts the title to default: `echo -ne '\e]2;\a'`

So... your best bet is to trick the remote `~/.bashrc` by setting a `TERM` other than `xterm*|rxvt*`, for example:

```sh
$ TERM=gnome-256color ssh ubuntu@remote.host.name
```

(IMHO, that's a pretty stupid restriction/policy. `~/.bashrc` is a file that only runs on *interactive* sessions, so it won't affect any script or service.  And the default `.bashrc` that ships by default in Ubuntu and other distros have this idiotic behavior of setting the title, it could/should be patched by devs/sysadmins when setting up their servers)