# change title for tabs in Terminator

Tags: terminator, tabs

I connect to many servers using Terminator and the tabs will display username@host

This is fine when I have a few tabs but once I get many tabs all I see is username...

Is there a way to display the title of the tabs to just hostname?

This is remote servers so updating my profile won't help.

Thanks

Comment: I use the `xttitle` package (`sudo apt install xttitle;man xttitle`).

Comment: I don't think that will work for what I want. I ssh to many servers in the same window; logging in and out of different servers. Every I ssh to a server the tab title has user@server.
So it is getting the tab title from the command I am entering; i.e ssh user@server

is there a way to have the tab tile just display server instead of user@server?

Comment: Read `man console_codes` then copy `printf "\e[2$USER@$HOSTNAME^G"` (`\e` is ESCape, `^G` is `Ctrl-G`) into your cut buffer and paste it into each window.  What user are you logging in at the "many servers", and why can't you do a little customization? Managing many servers is an area of practical computer administration. Many tools have been written to help. Do your research - don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The gnome-terminal of Ubuntu so ugly, the bad thing. You need to change to mate-terminal (apt install mate-terminal) and your question will be solved.

Then, open mate-terminal and config this one:
**Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Title
When terminal commands set their own titles: Keep initial title**

Now, you can try:

```
/usr/bin/mate-terminal --title=<WINDOW NAME> --tab <TAB NAME> -- <YOUR SSH SCRIPT>
```