# How do I change terminator title bar default text

Tags: command-line, terminator

I am using terminator  as my terminal. Currently its title always comes prefixed with `raj@raj-Lenovo` which is my username and host. SO if I `cd ~/test`. It would show `raj@raj-Lenovo ~/test` as the title.It makes it difficult to read the entire title when I `alt+Tab`. Is there anyway to change the prefix permanently? It would just show `~/test`. I couldnt find it through `GUI`.

Answer (score 1):

Most terminal emulators have an option to set the title bar default text, and it should work for terminator too.

Maybe this what you want?

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033]0; $("pwd") \a"'
```

It should change the title automatically even when you add new tab. See this link

[askubuntu.com/questions/636944/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-current-terminal-tab-using-only-the-command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636944/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-current-terminal-tab-using-only-the-command-line)

and if it works you can modify the `Exec` line in the corresponding desktop file.

Comment: where do i find the ``Exec`` line?

Comment: This sets the title permanantly to ``Hello World`` . But what I like is to just remove ``raj@Lenovo`` from title. Still have my working directory in title.

Comment: 1. I have not installed terminator, so I am not sure, but I think you should  find the file via this command: `find /usr/share -name terminator.desktop` I find the desktop files of 'my' terminal emulators with corresponding commands. 2. You can check at this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04 but I am not sure that it works for terminator.

Comment: But this permanantly changes the title. Thats not what  I want.

Comment: Maybe  this what you want? `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033]0; $("pwd") \a"'`