# Give a specific name to a terminal tab instance

Tags: command-line, tabs

*Edit : other answer talked about change the title of the terminal, not a tab, but effectively they answer to my question too. Everything is great.*

I'm a newbie and I wonder how give a specific name to a terminal tab instance ?

Here an instance of my question :

[image: instance : two tabs with custom names]

Currently I have just few knowledge in Ubuntu system.
Thanks

Comment: See:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177572/how-to-rename-terminal-tab-title-in-gnome-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I wrote a function for that once](https://askubuntu.com/a/860497/295286).

```
setTitle() {
    echo -e "\033]0;$@\007" 
}
```

Alternatively, one could use

```
 "\033]0;$@\a"
```

Using that in conjunction with  PROMPT_COMMAND variable in `~/.bashrc` or PS1 variable, you can do something like this:

```
PS1="$PS1$(setTitle $(date) )"
```

What this does is thatbit adds timestamp to title of the terminal each time you propt redrawing is called. So each of your tabs can have timestamp the last command got executed.

From there, you can add other forms of commands in `$()` instead of `date`. Or have  it be called from `~/.bashrc` once at the end of the file to only have non changing prompt through the session but unique for each tab.

See also:
[How to change the title of the current terminal tab using only the command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/636944/295286)