# Setting terminal window's title: wmctrl versus xdotool

Tags: command-line, xdotool, wmctrl

Edit: I am **not looking for other ways or better ways** to change a window's title or to add titles to tabs in terminals. The answers in the [proposed duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123710/how-to-set-the-title-in-terminal) **do not in any way** come close to addressing the specific issue of why `xdotool search …` **does not** pick up window titles when the title is set by *wmctrl* as described above.

---

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

When I open a *gnome-terminal* window, the title is *dkb@dkb:~*

I can change it using

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "NewName"
```

but `xdotool search …`, doesn't "see" this title:

```
dkb@dkb:~$ xdotool search --name NewName
dkb@dkb:~$
```

I just get back the prompt instead of being provided the corresponding window identifier.

On the other hand, I can use *xdotool* itself to set the title and then `xdotool search …` provides the window identifier:

```
dkb@dkb:~$ xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name NewName
dkb@dkb:~$ xdotool search --name NewName
39845894
dkb@dkb:~$
```

In other words, if the title is set by *xdotool*, `xdotool search` works as it should:

From `man xdotool`

> search [options] pattern   Search for windows with titles, names, or
>   classes with a regular expression pattern. The output is
>   line-delimited list of X window identifiers.

So while it's not a big deal, I'd like to know what the reason is for *xdotool* not "seeing" the window title set by *wmctrl.*

Comment: better solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123710/how-to-set-the-title-in-terminal/1123717#1123717

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the title in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123710/how-to-set-the-title-in-terminal)

Comment: @cmak.fr my question is specifically about why xdotool doesn't see the title set by wmctrl. Does the proposed duplicate address that issue? I don't think it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can see that at the very least `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname` works as intended.

```
$ wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "Test1"
$ xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
Test1
$ xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name Test2
$ xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
Test2
```

So let's go deeper. We can list properties of window using `xprop -id <id>` command. For window with name set by `wmctrl` it gives:

```
_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 1920, 995
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "brisk-menu-2514-mariusz-HP-Pavilion-Notebook-mate-terminal-1_TIME1314631"
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "mate-terminal-window-4442-66103825-1563868224"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 79691784, 79691785
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x4c00007
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x4c00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 4442
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "mariusz-HP-Pavilion-Notebook"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 345 by 141
        program specified resize increment: 9 by 20
        program specified base size: 16 by 30
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "mate-terminal", "Mate-terminal"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Terminal"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Test1"
```

And for for window with name set by `xdotool` it gives:

```
_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 1920, 995
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "brisk-menu-2514-mariusz-HP-Pavilion-Notebook-mate-terminal-1_TIME1314631"
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "mate-terminal-window-4442-66103825-1563868224"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 79691784, 79691785
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x4c00007
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x4c00001
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 4442
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "mariusz-HP-Pavilion-Notebook"
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified minimum size: 345 by 141
        program specified resize increment: 9 by 20
        program specified base size: 16 by 30
        window gravity: NorthWest
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "mate-terminal", "Mate-terminal"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Terminal"
_NET_WM_NAME(STRING) = "Test2"
```

And we can see that in both cases `_NET_WM_NAME` is set correctly. What is `_NET_WM_NAME`? It's an extension for x11 ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706589/is-there-any-difference-with-the-x11-atoms-xa-wm-name-and-net-wm-name), [link](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm140238712347280))

> _NET_WM_NAME
>
> _NET_WM_NAME, UTF8_STRING
>
> The Client SHOULD set this to the title of the window in UTF-8 encoding. If set, the Window Manager should use this in preference to
>   WM_NAME.

So x11 applications should prefer this property over `WM_NAME`. Let's display both of these properties. I've taken C code from [here](https://github.com/UltimateHackingKeyboard/current-window-linux/blob/master/get-current-window.c):

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTR 1000

Display *display;
unsigned long window;
unsigned char *prop;

void check_status(int status, unsigned long window)
{
    if (status == BadWindow) {
        printf("window id # 0x%lx does not exists!", window);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (status != Success) {
        printf("XGetWindowProperty failed!");
        exit(2);
    }
}

unsigned char* get_string_property(char* property_name)
{
    Atom actual_type, filter_atom;
    int actual_format, status;
    unsigned long nitems, bytes_after;

    filter_atom = XInternAtom(display, property_name, True);
    status = XGetWindowProperty(display, window, filter_atom, 0, MAXSTR, False, AnyPropertyType,
                                &actual_type, &actual_format, &nitems, &bytes_after, &prop);
    check_status(status, window);
    return prop;
}

unsigned long get_long_property(char* property_name)
{
    get_string_property(property_name);
    unsigned long long_property = prop[0] + (prop[1]<<8) + (prop[2]<<16) + (prop[3]<<24);
    return long_property;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *display_name = NULL;  // could be the value of $DISPLAY

    display = XOpenDisplay(display_name);
    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s:  unable to open display '%s'\n", argv[0], XDisplayName (display_name));
    }
    int screen = XDefaultScreen(display);
    window = RootWindow(display, screen);

    window = get_long_property("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW");

    printf("_NET_WM_PID: %lu\n", get_long_property("_NET_WM_PID"));
    printf("WM_CLASS: %s\n", get_string_property("WM_CLASS"));
    printf("_NET_WM_NAME: %s\n", get_string_property("_NET_WM_NAME"));
    printf("WM_NAME: %s\n", get_string_property("WM_NAME"));

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Only added a `printf("WM_NAME: %s\n", get_string_property("WM_NAME"));` line. Running:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -lX11
$ wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "Test1"
$ ./test 
_NET_WM_PID: 4442
WM_CLASS: mate-terminal
_NET_WM_NAME: Test1
WM_NAME: (null)
$ xdotool getactivewindow set_window --name Test2
$ ./test 
_NET_WM_PID: 4442
WM_CLASS: mate-terminal
_NET_WM_NAME: Test2
WM_NAME: Test2
```

So the conclusion is: `xdotool` sets both `_NET_WM_NAME` and `WN_NAME` but only search by `WM_NAME` and `wmctrl` sets only `_NET_WM_NAME`.

Comment: Actually there's no need for C, I could display properties just with `xprop -id <id> WM_NAME`