# In Ubuntu is there a way to configure PS1 so that it does not update the window title?

Tags: command-line, bash

### Question

I have a script called `title` which sets the title bar for a UNIX window, it's simple and just echos an escape sequence.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/22417/323009.

```
#/bin/bash
ESC=$'\e'
BELL='$'\a'
echo "${ESC};$*$BELL"
```

To use it I just type:

```
title tomcat logs
```

To make this work, however, I must also change the default PS1 setting because it breaks `title` because the default PS1 updates your title.

But I don't currently set PS1 in my $HOME/.bashrc file and I like the way PS1 works, I just want to stop PS1 from also updating my window title.  What's the fix?

**Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to manage PS1 the way it does but without updating my title?**

### Work Around

My current work around is to manually do this by finding how it's currently set.

```
echo $PS1
```

And then editing it so it removes the escape sequence which is updating the title.

```
PS1="\u@\h \w: "
```

#### The solution I'd like to have

By this day and age, I would have expected this to be configurable so that I could say in my `.bashrc` file.  NOTE: Putty allows this to be changed, see https://superuser.com/a/919770/331605

```
DONT_UPDATE_TITLE=true
 . . . rest of normal .bashrc file
```

And the code that sets PS1 would not update the title but continue updating the PS1 prompt as it currently does.

### Searching for a solution

There are many questions asking similar questions but none asking this one.

Below are links I've found helpful some in StackOverflow, Ubuntu, and Superuser.

- [How to change Gnome-Terminal title?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)
- [Setting terminal window's title: wmctrl versus xdotool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160319/setting-terminal-windows-title-wmctrl-versus-xdotool?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832308/how-do-you-write-a-esc-character-to-be-interpreted-by-echo
- https://superuser.com/questions/510900/putty-title-changes-after-login
- https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html

Answer (score 1):

`PS1` can be set in your `~/.bashrc`. If it isn't, you get the `PS1` that was set earlier (see "Startup Files" in `man bash`.

The values you set into `PS1`, and their effects, is documented in `man bash`, the section on "Prompting".

Look at what is in your `PS1` with `echo "$PS1" | od -bc`.

Aside from `PS1`, when I want this behavior (update title upon `cd`), I replace the `cd` command with a `bash` function, defined in my `~/.bashrc`, that does the `cd` and sets the title. See `type cd` to check if your `cd` command has been replaced. The function that replaced `cd` was defined in one of the startup files, see paragraph 1.

Comment: The question I'm asking is this:  **Is it possible to set a value (variable) in my `.bashrc` that causes the default system files that currently set PS1 to work as they do now, but without setting the window title?**